# How to get an image to change when a button is clicked?

Tags: javascript, html

I have a div tag which holds an image that is picked at random from a if statement.
My image src are in a number of different arrays sorted via topic. What I am having  difficulties with is the image changing when my go button is clicked I would like the if statement to repeat giving a new image from a different topic , am I missing something simple here ? I fairly new to javascript so any help would be appreciated.

Comment: First, rather then using `if` you should use a `switch` with `case 1` etc.  Also, to change an image you can have a placeholder and toggle it. `<img src="" id="theimage" style="display:none"/>` then in JS `document.getElementById("theImage").style.display=""; document.getElementById("theImage").src="images/newImage.png";`

Answer (score 1):

The main issue seems to be the way you are trying to replace the existing image.

`document.write = image;`

The previous line replaces the native `document.write` function with your image markup, wich is obviously not what you want.

**Without re-writing all your code**, what you could do is find the div that holds the image and replace it's `innerHTML` property with the content of your `image` variable.

```
document.getElementById('div_that_hold_the_image').innerHTML = image;
```

*Please note that if that div contains other children, they will all be removed*

**I strongly advise you to read more on JavaScript. Even tough your code will run, it has plenty of issues that should be adressed.**

For instance, you should not rely on global variables to pass data around and you don't need to evaluate a string literal using `()` before assigning it to a variable.

`topic=("Tv Shows");` can just be `topic = "Tv Shows";`

Comment: Thank you that worked , also I have taken a look over code conventions for the JavaScript and plan restructure my code tomorrow you have been a great help.